# Google Sheets: Average data points with same X value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I couldn't think of a better title, but here's what I have:

[image]

I want a graph of X and Y, but when there's multiple Y values for an X value, I want it to plot the average of the Y values.

Here's what I've tried:

I noticed that if I have two identical X,Y pairs, the graph will show them as a single point - so if I can create a column that averages out the Y values for the same X, I can graph that and get what I want (although I haven't been able to do that either).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column called "Average Y"

In the first cell, use the following formula: `=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A1,B:B)`

Where `A` is your column of X values and `B` is your column of Y values.

In the same table as OP, result looks like:

[image]

And your resulting graph looks as expected (no duplicate points):
[image]